# systemd timer unexpected behaviour

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, systemd

The question I am asking is related to systemd timer and it's behaviour. I found an example on how to work with systemd timer [here](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-timers-for-scheduling-tasks/).

Even though the link I provided is link to a site that's fedora oriented, this specific topic is not limited to red-hat based distributions. I tried to do the same on my lubuntu 20.04 and even though it works, it doesn't work the way I expected.
Basically, I just created a script that outputs some text in the file (including current time) specified and then I created `.service` and corresponding `.timer` files, the same way it is done in the example given in the link I provided. The problem is with the following lines in `schedule-test.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Schedule a message every 1 minute
RefuseManualStart=no
RefuseManualStop=no

[Timer]
#Execute job if it missed a run due to machine being off
Persistent=true
#Run 120 seconds after boot for the first time
OnBootSec=120
#Run every 1 minute thereafter
OnUnitActiveSec=60
#File describing job to execute
Unit=schedule-test.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

So basically, one would expect that this timer would run `schedule-test.service` 120 seconds after boot and then every 60 seconds while running. However, the opposite happens, here's the portion of the file in which the script writes it's output:

```
This is only a test: Sat 30 Jul 2022 08:43:41 AM 
This is only a test: Sat 30 Jul 2022 08:45:41 AM 
This is only a test: Sat 30 Jul 2022 08:47:41 AM 
This is only a test: Sat 30 Jul 2022 08:49:41 AM
This is only a test: Sat 30 Jul 2022 08:51:41 AM
```

As can be seen, the script runs every 120 seconds when system is running even though
`OnUnitActiveSec=60`. What am I doing wrong here, is my reasoning wrong or this doesn't work the way it should for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`systemd` timers are not accurate to the second by default ... They are allowed a window of 1 minute from either(*in your case*) `OnBootSec=` or `OnUnitActiveSec=` and others(*`OnCalendar=, OnActiveSec=, OnStartupSec= and OnUnitInactiveSec=`*) ... This is a default power saving feature, but you can bring the accuracy down to 1 second(*while the minimum and most accurate is 1 [microsecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) i.e. `AccuracySec=1 us`*) by setting [`AccuracySec=1`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#AccuracySec=) and adding it as an extra entry to your timer unit like so:

```
[Unit]
Description=Schedule a message every 1 minute
RefuseManualStart=no
RefuseManualStop=no

[Timer]
#Execute job if it missed a run due to machine being off
Persistent=true
#Set the timer accuracy to 1 second instead of the default 1 minute
AccuracySec=1
#Run 120 seconds after boot for the first time
OnBootSec=120
#Run every 1 minute thereafter
OnUnitActiveSec=60
#File describing job to execute
Unit=schedule-test.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```